# Why is my webscraping script only retrieving 500 out of 1000 urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

**Brief description:** I am trying to retrieve all listing urls in H&M's dresses page. I have already been able to webscrape the first 500 listing urls. I am not able to webscrape the next ~500.

**What I'm trying to do:** Retrieve all listings urls in H&M's dresses page.

**What I've done:** I've implemented the code below and have been able to retrieve all urls from the first 500 product listings (out of ~1000).

**The problem:** I think there might be some restrictions on how many requests I can make. The obvious answer is to split this up into the first 500 and next 500 requests, but I'm not sure how to do this. Currently, I set the website url's "page-size" parameter in "params" to about ~1000 listings (the actual number of listings on the page), which should return listings 0 to ~1000 (but returns 0-500). The only way I could get listings 500-1000 is if I could set a range for the page-size parameter, but I can't. Any ideas?

**Code: **

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import numpy as np
import json
import re
from ast import literal_eval
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import random

headers = headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}

base_url = "https://www2.hm.com/en_us/women/products/dresses.html"

response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
pagination_element = soup.find('div', class_='filter-pagination')
items_text = pagination_element.get_text(strip=True)
num_listings = int(items_text.split()[0])


params = {
    "sort": "stock",
    "image-size": "small",
    "image": "model",
    "offset": 0,
    "page-size": num_listings
}

response = requests.get(base_url, params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

listing_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select(".item-link")]

print(f'Listings collected: {len(listing_urls)}')
print(f"Total number of listings: {num_listings}")
print(f'Listing URLs 1-5: {listing_urls[:5]}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use their Ajax pagination API:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}

url = "https://www2.hm.com/en_us/women/products/dresses/_jcr_content/main/productlisting.display.json"

params = {
    "sort": "stock",
    "image-size": "small",
    "image": "model",
    "offset": "0",
    "page-size": "36",
}

all_products = []
for offset in range(0, 36 * 3, 36):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    print(f"{offset=}")
    params["offset"] = offset
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
    all_products.extend(data["products"])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_products)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
offset=0
offset=36
offset=72


  articleCode                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   onClick                                link                        title                        category                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      image legalText promotionalMarkerText  showPromotionalClubMarker  showPriceMarker                                                                                           favouritesTracking favouritesSavedText favouritesNotSavedText marketingMarkerText marketingMarkerType marketingMarkerCss    price redPrice yellowPrice bluePrice clubPriceText sellingAttribute swatchesTotal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              swatches preAccessStartDate preAccessEndDate preAccessGroups outOfStockText comingSoon brandName damStyleWith
0  0979874001  setOsaParameters(utag_data.category_id,'SMALL','0979874001'); setNotificationTicket('Oy9wbHAvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0LXdpdGgtY291bnQvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0OyM7cHJvZHVjdF9rZXk7MDk3OTg3NF9ncm91cF8wMDFfZW5fdXM7MDk3OTg3NDAwMV9lbl91cztPQkpFQ1RJVkUkO05PTkU6Tk9ORTs5OTs','0979874001');  /en_us/productpage.0979874001.html             Sweatshirt Dress     ladies_basics_dressesskirts                                         [{'src': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/84/74/8474cbb3656a7a00c234f451bfbc8a4cc62db7c5.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'dataAltImage': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/5f/55/5f55b8a40c9fe1c49374a6b10a2478a515febf62.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_basics_dressesskirts],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'alt': 'Sweatshirt Dress Model', 'dataAltText': 'Sweatshirt Dress'}]                                                      False            False             Favourites|0979874001|Sweatshirt Dress|LADIES_SHOPBYPRODUCT : DRESSES_DRESSES : VIEWALL_VIEW_ALL   SAVED AS FAVORITE       SAVE AS FAVORITE                                                             $ 24.99                                                                           5  [{'colorCode': '#272628', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874001.html', 'colorName': 'Black'}, {'colorCode': '#515359', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874011.html', 'colorName': 'Dark gray'}, {'colorCode': '#86917A', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874013.html', 'colorName': 'Khaki green'}, {'colorCode': '#86917A', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874015.html', 'colorName': 'Khaki green'}]                                                  []                                 H&M             
1  1109917007  setOsaParameters(utag_data.category_id,'SMALL','1109917007'); setNotificationTicket('Oy9wbHAvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0LXdpdGgtY291bnQvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0OyM7cHJvZHVjdF9rZXk7MTEwOTkxN19ncm91cF8wMDdfZW5fdXM7MTEwOTkxNzAwN19lbl91cztPQkpFQ1RJVkUkO05PTkU6Tk9ORTs5OTs','1109917007');  /en_us/productpage.1109917007.html               Rib-knit Dress  ladies_dresses_longsleevedress                                          [{'src': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/ad/79/ad79561ecb2ab9fdb3c77cd0aff996628b63bd6a.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'dataAltImage': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/de/e9/dee94a36a5898f9008680f79070bf271bf6d5790.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_dresses_longsleevedress],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'alt': 'Rib-knit Dress Model', 'dataAltText': 'Rib-knit Dress'}]                                                      False            False               Favourites|1109917007|Rib-knit Dress|LADIES_SHOPBYPRODUCT : DRESSES_DRESSES : VIEWALL_VIEW_ALL   SAVED AS FAVORITE       SAVE AS FAVORITE                                                             $ 39.99                                                                           3                                                                                                              [{'colorCode': '#EEEDE1', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.1109917007.html', 'colorName': 'Light beige'}, {'colorCode': '#272628', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.1109917001.html', 'colorName': 'Black'}, {'colorCode': '#4B262D', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.1109917006.html', 'colorName': 'Burgundy'}]                                                  []                                 H&M             
2  0979874020  setOsaParameters(utag_data.category_id,'SMALL','0979874020'); setNotificationTicket('Oy9wbHAvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0LXdpdGgtY291bnQvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0OyM7cHJvZHVjdF9rZXk7MDk3OTg3NF9ncm91cF8wMjBfZW5fdXM7MDk3OTg3NDAyMF9lbl91cztPQkpFQ1RJVkUkO05PTkU6Tk9ORTs5OTs','0979874020');  /en_us/productpage.0979874020.html             Sweatshirt Dress     ladies_basics_dressesskirts  [{'src': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/0c/68/0c686143cd3c02a69f8f19f64ab26200983ae51b.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_basics_dressesskirts],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'dataAltImage': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/0c/68/0c686143cd3c02a69f8f19f64ab26200983ae51b.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_basics_dressesskirts],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'alt': 'Sweatshirt Dress Model', 'dataAltText': 'Sweatshirt Dress'}]                                                      False            False             Favourites|0979874020|Sweatshirt Dress|LADIES_SHOPBYPRODUCT : DRESSES_DRESSES : VIEWALL_VIEW_ALL   SAVED AS FAVORITE       SAVE AS FAVORITE                                                             $ 24.99                                                   New Arrival             5  [{'colorCode': '#DFD8C9', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874020.html', 'colorName': 'Light beige'}, {'colorCode': '#272628', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874001.html', 'colorName': 'Black'}, {'colorCode': '#515359', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874011.html', 'colorName': 'Dark gray'}, {'colorCode': '#86917A', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.0979874013.html', 'colorName': 'Khaki green'}]                                                  []                                 H&M             
3  1189024001  setOsaParameters(utag_data.category_id,'SMALL','1189024001'); setNotificationTicket('Oy9wbHAvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0LXdpdGgtY291bnQvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0OyM7cHJvZHVjdF9rZXk7MTE4OTAyNF9ncm91cF8wMDFfZW5fdXM7MTE4OTAyNDAwMV9lbl91cztPQkpFQ1RJVkUkO05PTkU6Tk9ORTs5OTs','1189024001');  /en_us/productpage.1189024001.html  Balloon-sleeved Satin Dress            ladies_dresses_party                                              [{'src': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/38/71/3871b10536aaa49a40d5254713a7cff4f8f12a96.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'dataAltImage': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/06/2f/062f95cfc20fd9481cdd0bea81f84d1cd18cb9e8.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'alt': 'Balloon-sleeved Satin Dress Model', 'dataAltText': 'Balloon-sleeved Satin Dress'}]                                                      False            False  Favourites|1189024001|Balloon-sleeved Satin Dress|LADIES_SHOPBYPRODUCT : DRESSES_DRESSES : VIEWALL_VIEW_ALL   SAVED AS FAVORITE       SAVE AS FAVORITE                                                             $ 37.99                                                                           1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [{'colorCode': '#61806E', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.1189024001.html', 'colorName': 'Green'}]                                                  []                                 H&M             
4  1193445001  setOsaParameters(utag_data.category_id,'SMALL','1193445001'); setNotificationTicket('Oy9wbHAvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0LXdpdGgtY291bnQvcHJvZHVjdC1saXN0OyM7cHJvZHVjdF9rZXk7MTE5MzQ0NV9ncm91cF8wMDFfZW5fdXM7MTE5MzQ0NTAwMV9lbl91cztPQkpFQ1RJVkUkO05PTkU6Tk9ORTs5OTs','1193445001');  /en_us/productpage.1193445001.html     Twist-detail Satin Dress      ladies_dresses_mididresses                                                    [{'src': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/ab/17/ab17aad0e7bc8e0b14d4272b06f06de9406c6baf.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'dataAltImage': '//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/02/0c/020ce4ced26164e134c5b6aa914c6ba8891e6476.jpg],origin[dam],category[],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/style]', 'alt': 'Twist-detail Satin Dress Model', 'dataAltText': 'Twist-detail Satin Dress'}]                                                      False            False     Favourites|1193445001|Twist-detail Satin Dress|LADIES_SHOPBYPRODUCT : DRESSES_DRESSES : VIEWALL_VIEW_ALL   SAVED AS FAVORITE       SAVE AS FAVORITE                                                             $ 64.99                                                                           1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [{'colorCode': '#DFD8C9', 'articleLink': '/en_us/productpage.1193445001.html', 'colorName': 'Cream/black striped'}]                                                  []                                 H&M
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Question: is there a way to find the number of listings on the page using just requests.get() ? Previously, I used BeautifulSoup (see code for "num_listings")

Comment: @Danny_webb The total number of listings is stored in `data["total"]`. You can do `print(data)` and see, what other information is there.

Comment: I meant before entering the for loop. Because I need to know the # of pages for the for loop, so I first need to figure out the # of total dress listings & divide that by 36. I would check this manually, but it changes often. The # of listings is an element on the first page of the base url. I think I figured it out though, but thank you.

Comment: @Danny_webb Before entering the loop, make one request with offset=0 and see, what is inside `data["total"]`

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to repeat this example but for a different website (https://www.jcrew.com/plp/womens/categories/clothing/dresses-and-jumpsuits?Npge=1&Nrpp=60) . Could you explain how you found that .json URL for the h&m website, so I can do the same for the jcrew website? Thanks